How to identify a script that is setting an environment variable
I've got a problem in that I want to run a python script using requests.
import requests

f = requests.get("https://dclgapps.communities.gov.uk/imd/iod_index.html#")

It returns an error:
{
    "name": "InvalidURL",
    "message": "Failed to parse: http://proxyserver:port",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LocationParseError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:460, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    458     os.environ['https_proxy'] = ''
--> 460     conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
    461 except LocationValueError as e:

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:343, in HTTPAdapter.get_connection(self, url, proxies)
    342 if proxy:
--> 343     proxy = prepend_scheme_if_needed(proxy, \"http\")
    344     proxy_url = parse_url(proxy)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/utils.py:993, in prepend_scheme_if_needed(url, new_scheme)
    988 \"\"\"Given a URL that may or may not have a scheme, prepend the given scheme.
    989 Does not replace a present scheme with the one provided as an argument.
    990 
    991 :rtype: str
    992 \"\"\"
--> 993 parsed = parse_url(url)
    994 scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parsed

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/url.py:397, in parse_url(url)
    396 except (ValueError, AttributeError):
--> 397     return six.raise_from(LocationParseError(source_url), None)
    399 # For the sake of backwards compatibility we put empty
    400 # string values for path if there are any defined values
    401 # beyond the path in the URL.
    402 # TODO: Remove this when we break backwards compatibility.

File <string>:3, in raise_from(value, from_value)

LocationParseError: Failed to parse: http://proxyserver:port

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidURL                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 f = requests.get(\"https://dclgapps.communities.gov.uk/imd/iod_index.html#\")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py:73, in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     62 def get(url, params=None, **kwargs):
     63     r\"\"\"Sends a GET request.
     64 
     65     :param url: URL for the new :class:`Request` object.
   (...)
     70     :rtype: requests.Response
     71     \"\"\"
---> 73     return request(\"get\", url, params=params, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/api.py:59, in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     55 # By using the 'with' statement we are sure the session is closed, thus we
     56 # avoid leaving sockets open which can trigger a ResourceWarning in some
     57 # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     58 with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 59     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:589, in Session.request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    584 send_kwargs = {
    585     \"timeout\": timeout,
    586     \"allow_redirects\": allow_redirects,
    587 }
    588 send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 589 resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    591 return resp

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:703, in Session.send(self, request, **kwargs)
    700 start = preferred_clock()
    702 # Send the request
--> 703 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    705 # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
    706 elapsed = preferred_clock() - start

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py:462, in HTTPAdapter.send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    460     conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
    461 except LocationValueError as e:
--> 462     raise InvalidURL(e, request=request)
    464 self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
    465 url = self.request_url(request, proxies)

InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http://proxyserver:port"
}

When I check with
env

I get the results:
http_proxy=http://proxyserver:port
https_proxy=http://proxyserver:port

How do I identify the script/s that are doing this? Grep seems a way to go because the usual suspects .zshrc, .bashrc, .profile don't seem to be doing it.
